# why after saving meta value it's saving all the values the one that i clicked?

Tags: post-meta, meta-value

I have a code that save meta post and show them to the visitors:

```
<?php if(is_singular( 'manga' ) ){
                        $manga_link=get_post_meta($post->ID,"featured_fields_manga",true);
                        $count_season = get_post_meta($post->ID,"featured_fields_manga",true);
                        if($manga_link){
                            ?>
                            <div class="download-series">
                                <?php
                                foreach( $count_season as $key){
                                    $num_ar[] = $key['season_serie'];
                                }
                                $num_arr = array_unique($num_ar);
                                foreach($num_arr as $numi){
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="down-row-serie">
                                        <?php
                                        foreach( $manga_link as $season){
                                            $meta = $season['season_serie'];
                                            switch($meta){
                                                case $meta === $numi:
                                                    ?>
                                                    <div class="wppper-line">
                                                        <div class="chapright">
                                                            <ul class="meta">
                                                                <?php if(!empty($season['quality_serie'])){?><li><span>name</span><?php echo $season['quality_serie'];?> </li><?php }?>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="chapleft">
                                                            <ul class="dl">
                                                                <a id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="your_class_to_update">save this in meta field</a>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <?php
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php }?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }} ?>
```

until now every thing is ok. now i want: after a visitor click "save this in meta field", the "name" and one more data ("chap") should save in a new meta key (i know it's better to save in user meta and now i'm just trying to save in post meta). the code is this (this code has issue because after user clicked "save this in meta field" all "name" and "chap" in this post will save in post meta. I want to save only that one i clicked):

```
function custom_update_post() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $post_meta_name = get_post_meta($post_id, 'name-manga-en',true);
    $first_link = get_post_meta($post_id,"featured_fields_manga", true);
    if($first_link){
        ?>
        <?php
        foreach( $first_link as $season){
            ?>
        <?php
    $meta = array(
        'chap'          => $post_meta_name,
        'name'          => $season['quality_serie']
    );
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta', $meta );
        }}
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_update_post', 'custom_update_post' );
```

js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('.your_class_to_update').on('click', function() {
        var post_id = $(this).attr( 'id' );
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'custom_update_post',
                post_id: post_id
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I hope that i explained well. to be more clear see this picture:
[image: more explanation]
for example i want to save only "11 تا 20" not "11 تا 20 and 1 تا 10 and 86".
what is wrong?

this is more explanation for what Tom J Nowell asked:

at the first code we have a class named "your_class_to_update". when user clicks on "save this in meta field" that has this class, script loads with ajax and recognize the code that is in the functions.

now about meta data: there is a meta_key in the post meta named "featured_fields_manga". this meta_key has meta_value that stores some data in array. sth like this:

quality_serie: 86 linkdown: link1

quality_serie: 120 linkdown: link2

i can echo these data with the first code and show them to user. now i want that when user click on "save this in meta field" (it's beside every multiple data. for example beside 86 and link1 (you can see this in the picture)) only 86 be saved in a new meta_key. note that my first and third code is working fine. the problem is the second code (function that saves this data after user clicked). this wrong code saves all the values with "quality_serie". is it clear now?

Comment: the javascript is missing from your question

Comment: there is no problem in js code. I edited the question and added the js. tnks for your reply

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how it knows which meta and its value it needs to save in the AJAX call, only the post ID is being sent. Where are these fields coming from and what is the purpose of this functionality? Can you provide some context behind this? It's very difficult to understand what this is trying to implement. Are you trying to set a particular `quality_serie` as the single featured `quality_serie` of that post? This looks like an X Y problem

Comment: You just posted your reply as the solution to your question, you need to edit your question to include the information. Now people will think that you've found your solution and no longer need help

Comment: I've deleted your answer, can you include the information directly in your question? Remember this isn't a discussion forum. Use the edit link underneath the tags to modify and improve your question. Also, your response was very technical, but provided no background context explaining what you're trying to implement, what does the button actually do from a user perspective? What is the feature that you're trying to implement by doing this?

Comment: it's part of a personal system that i'm building and it's my only problem right now. do you know where the problem of my second code is? i explained in the post that you deleted and i don't know how to be more clear!

Comment: What does the system do? Your explanations focus exclusively on the technical side of things, but it's very difficult to understand how to fix it if we do not know what it does

Comment: right now, I just want to save the certain data that i mentioned before in the new meta_key.

Comment: you can look at this like a favorite button that gets a certain data and store it in database. so the user can see what he saved (as i said before, i know it should be saved in user meta. it's just a test right now and will be modified later).

Comment: ok, now that you've said that, I don't need to understand your code to write an answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok so we have *things*, and we want to favourite/unfavourite them as done. First, we need 2 functions:

- `saeed_is_favourited( int $post_id, string $thing_to_favourite )` ( where `$thing_to_favourite` is the thing we're marking as saved/favourited/etc, and `$default` is the value to return if we don't know yet
- `saeed_set_favourited( int $post_id, string $thing_to_favourite, bool $favourited )` where we set `$thing_to_favourite` on that post as favourited or not favourited

Then you will need a way to send an AJAX request to call `saeed_set_favourited` with the requested value.

We will store if it's favourited in user meta using a user meta with a key like this:

```
saeed_favourite_123_ABC
```

Where `123` is the post ID, and `ABC` is the thing we're favouriting/not favouriting. This *thing* is a string, any string of your choosing. In the examples I give, it is completely arbitrary. It is not the slug of a post or a meta key, or a username. I could use those if I wanted, or I could make them up.

---

Here is an attempt at implementing `saeed_is_favourited`

```php
function saeed_is_favourited( int $post_id, string $thing_to_favourite ) : bool {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $meta_key = 'saeed_favourited_' . $post_id . '_' . $thing_to_favourite;
    $result = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true );
    return boolval( $result );
}
```

Used like this:

```php
if ( saeed_is_favourited( get_the_ID(), 'apples' ) ) {
    echo "you have favourited apples on this post";
} else {
    echo "you have not favourited apples on this post";
}
```

---

Here is an attempt at implementing `saeed_set_favourited`

```php
function saeed_set_favourited( int $post_id, string $thing_to_favourite, bool $favourited ) : void {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $meta_key = 'saeed_favourited_' . $post_id . '_' . $thing_to_favourite;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $favourited );
}
```

Notice that I used `update_user_meta`, not `add_user_meta`. `add_user_meta` can create multiple meta key/value pairs, meta keys are not unique.

---

Finally, we need a way to set if it has been favourited or not. Here is an old style Admin AJAX handler:

```php
function saeed_ajax_favourite_a_thing() : void {
    $post_id = 0;
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['post_id'] ) {
        $post_id = intval( $_POST['post_id'] );
    } else {
        wp_die( 'a post_id number is needed, none was provided' );
    }

    $thing_to_favourite = '';
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['thing_to_favourite'] ) {
        $thing_to_favourite = $_POST['thing_to_favourite'];
    } else {
        wp_die( 'a thing_to_favourite is needed, none was provided' );
    }

    $favourite = false;
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['favourite'] ) {
        $favourite = boolval( $_POST['favourite'] );
    } else {
        wp_die( 'a favourite is needed, either true or false, none was provided' );
    }
    saeed_set_favourited( $post_id, $thing_to_favourite, $favourite );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_saeed_ajax_favourite_a_thing', 'saeed_ajax_favourite_a_thing' );
```

You would then pass a post ID, a thing_to_favourite representing the thing you want to favourite, and a true/false for wether it is to be favourited or unfavourited.

E.g. this would favourite `apple`:

```js
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'saeed_ajax_favourite_a_thing',
                post_id: post_id
                thing_to_favourite: 'apple',
                favourite: true
            }
        });
```

---

You should consider looking into the more modern REST API endpoints as a cleaner replacement for this AJAX handler.

You can also use `saeed_is_favourited` to construct your frontend, and the AJAX to toggle the items on/off.

Because it used user meta, the favouriting will work on a per user basis.

You will want to check `is_user_logged_in()` as this code will not work for logged out users.

***Note that none of this code is tested, you may need to make modifications after integrating it into your code***

Comment: thanks for your answer. $key shouldn't be static. it should get the $key from post meta "featured_fields_manga" (one of the "quality_serie" that we clicked). the problem is here. I don't know how to distinguish one "quality_serie" with another "quality_serie" in this post. if we can distinguish this, then we can put it in the meta_value and problem will be solved

Comment: I do not understand, what is a `quality_serie`? You've jumped ahead without explaining any of the context or backstory. I know that you think it's unnecessary, but it is necessary. Your data structure is a mystery, you focus on just this sub-section without explanation. You've narrowed things down too far and made them too specific

Comment: As I understand it, you already have a loop for each season: `foreach( $manga_link as $season){` and code to display each item, so I do not see the problem? Just use `$season['quality_serie']` as the key. The key can literally be anything you want, `$key` is not referring to a user meta or post meta, it's just a unique identifier

Comment: I have renamed it to `thing_to_favourite` to emphasise that the functions/AJAX are not wanting a meta key. In my examples `apple` is not a meta key. Your `featured_fields_manga` contains values. Use the values!